# Esper: create window for events that occur after another event

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I want mean speed (sensor=1) at different power settings 1-10 (sensor=2). I don't want speeds from sensor one to be included in the mean calculation if they occurred before the change in setting (sensor=2).

E.g. power_setting=1, speed=50, speed=60, power_setting=2, speed=100, speed=120

If I took a time window around power_setting = 2, then it may include a speed for power_setting = 1.

How do I explicitly tell esper to only calculate with values that occured after the power setting change.

Here is my current script:

```
CREATE window SpeedWindow.win:time_batch(30 sec) as (speed double, power_setting int);

INSERT into SpeedWindow
SELECT
    speedEvent.value as speed,
    powerSetting.value as power_setting
FROM
    Sensors(id = 1).std:lastevent() as speedEvent,
    Sensors(id = 2).std:lastevent() as powerSetting;

INSERT into Output
SELECT
    case
        when SpeedWindowEvent.power_setting = 1 then 4154
        when SpeedWindowEvent.power_setting = 2 then 4155
        ... etc ...
    end as id,
    avg(SpeedWindowEvent.speed) as value
FROM
    SpeedWindow as SpeedWindowEvent
GROUP BY
    SpeedWindowEvent.power_setting;
```

Comment: I don't understand this just yet. For the event s2=1, s1=50, s1=60, s2=2, s1=100, s1=120, which ones should be ignored and why?

Comment: I am giving them in the order they occur. If a speed event (s1) occurs before a power setting (s2) it is irrelevant when calculating mean at power setting = X. So I want mean speed at all power settings, but only on speed data that occurs after that power setting is activated.

Comment: So speed settings are "s1" events and power settings are "s2" events right? Why not just name them power and speed? i.e. "insert into Speed select * from Sensor(id=1)" and "insert into Power select * from Sensor(id=2)" helps so much. For the event sequence "speed=1, power=50, power=60, speed=2, power=100, power=120" what is the output and upon which event and what speed events are ignored .....?

Comment: so for speed 1 in that sequence: it should calculate for power=50 and power=60 and for speed 2 power=100 and power=120. So only for events that occur after the setting is activated and before the setting is changed again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments clarifying the use case. Create a context that initiates and terminates on speed event.

```
// make it easy to read, takes no CPU at all
insert into Speed select * from Sensor(id=1);
insert into Power select * from Sensor(id=2);

create context SpeedSession initiated by Speed terminated by Speed;
context SpeedSession select avg(...) from Power;
```